# Amazon Athena S3 Prefix

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-elb, amazon-athena

i am running the below query in athena

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS elb_logs (
 request_timestamp string,
 elb_name string,
 request_ip string,
 request_port int,
 backend_ip string,
 backend_port int,
 request_processing_time double,
 backend_processing_time double,
 client_response_time double,
 elb_response_code string,
 backend_response_code string,
 received_bytes bigint,
 sent_bytes bigint,
 request_verb string,
 url string,
 protocol string,
 user_agent string,
 ssl_cipher string,
 ssl_protocol string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 'serialization.format' = '1',
 'input.regex' = '([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*):([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)[:\-]([0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) (|[-0-9]*) (-|[-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) \\\"([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (- |[^ ]*)\\\" (\"[^\"]*\") ([A-Z0-9-]+) ([A-Za-z0-9.-]*)$' )
LOCATION 's3://your_log_bucket/prefix/AWSLogs/AWS_account_ID/elasticloadbalancing/';
```

in this query we need to mention the S3 location as follows

```
s3://your_log_bucket/prefix/AWSLogs/AWS_account_ID/elasticloadbalancing/
```

what is the prefix that is mentioned in this
`s3://your_log_bucket/prefix/AWSLogs/AWS_account_ID/elasticloadbalancing/` the S3 location for logs  is actually this `s3://your_log_bucket/AWSLogs/AWS_account_ID/elasticloadbalancing/`

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If your logs location is `s3://your_log_bucket/AWSLogs/AWS_account_ID/elasticloadbalancing/` then you don't need to define prefix value, simply keep this s3 location in Athena table's location.

FYI, Say if multiple api's load balancers are generating logs data in same s3 buckets, There would be different s3 path such as  `s3://your_log_bucket/api-v1`, `s3://your_log_bucket/api-v2` etc. here prefix is api-v1 while s3 location would be s3://your_log_bucket/api-v1/AWSLogs/AWS_account_ID/elasticloadbalancing/